# Is it possible to use the new Android app bundle architecture with RN 0.57?

Tags: android, react-native, android-app-bundle

App bundles: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/ This allows Google Play to manage signing, decrease the app size, and allows for pulling code on demand which is really awesome!

I tried setting this up but Android studio kept telling me I need to update my gradle version?

Here is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4' //version required
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        /**
         * Must stay in this order
         */
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

Is it possible for me to be able to use the app bundles? Or will I have to install wait until the RN community supports it?

Answer (score 24):

You don’t necessarily need to use Android Studio to compile a release build of a React Native project.

Normally you would use this command to compile a release build.

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

If you want to use Android App Bundle, you use the following instead.

`./gradlew bundleRelease`

The resulting build will be found in this folder: 
`android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab`

This blog elaborates more on the steps.

https://blog.swmansion.com/make-your-react-native-app-3x-smaller-44c993eda2c9

Comment: My project is at React Native version 53 and when I run de command `./gradlew bundleRelease` it runs succesful but nothing is generated. It only works on Reactn Native 59+?

Answer (score 0):

It's already possible to publish React Native apps with the Android App Bundle. The support is in Android Studio and Gradle since 3.2.0.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? Is it enabled by default or do we need to configure something on the gradle files? Should we use it with precautions like when using proguard on RN?

Comment: Have you managed to set up to get Android App Bundle with RN?